# How to do a cascade filtering using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table a such

| Env | depot | articles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | AAA | Capacitor |
| 100 | AbA | Diode |
| 100 | AAA | cable |
| 100 | AbA | mike |
| 100 | ABC | modem |
| 900 |  |  |

Im extracting  my data from a postgres database using php and it's working fine

Now i'm wanting to do a cascade filter  to show for a specific **Env** the **depot** associated and the **articles** under that articles **depot**

For example , if i select in my dropdownlist **Env** = 100 , dropdownlist **dépot** would show me  AAA / AbA / ABC  then when i select **AAA** dropdowlist **Articles** will show **Capacitor / cable**

if i select in my dropdownlist **Env** = 900 , dropdownlist **dépot** would show me  nothing  so on in dropdowlist **Articles**

This is a sample of Data but my table contains more values    .

Here is my code that tried but couldn't reach desired output

```js
var options = $('#env').val();
var selectOptions = '';

for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  selectOptions += '<option value="' + options[i] + '">' + options[i] + '</option>';
}

$('#env').append(selectOptions).on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

  $('#depot, #articles').empty();

  $.each(envs, function(i, v) {;
    if (v.env == selected) {
      $('#depot').append('<option value="' + v.depot + '">' + v.depot + '</option>');
      $('#articles').append('<option value="' + v.articles + '">' + v.articles + '</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not filter in database too? Anyway, you do not apply `v.depot` check anywhere.

Comment: how could i filter in database ?

Comment: With conditions `SELECT ... FROM .. WHERE env = :env AND depot = :depot`

Comment: in my php tag you mean ?  how could i enject it using code ? could you explain more please ? since it's a sql query in a single table i don't have problem using it but i couldn't get the point how to use varaibles

Comment: @Justinas do ou want me to update my question putting the query that i'm using to full the dropdown lists ?